# project dependent variables in pkg-config

Tags: ruby, pkg-config

I'm trying to help the Ruby guys get the code working again on AIX.  The Ruby guys are trying to use pkg-config to help users write modules.  On AIX, the final link of the module needs to specify the entry point.  In Ruby, the convention is to name that entry point Init_foo where "foo" is the module that is being added.  Thus they need to add a flag: -eInit_foo

But since Init_foo is not a constant, pkg-config barfs when the ruby.pc file is given to pkg-config.  I don't see a way to have variables in the pkg-config file that depend upon the target.

I thought I would ask here how this problem might be solved.

Comment: It's been a while since I see ruby extensions so I might be off topic. But, why do you have to use pkg-config for _a target depending variable_?  The target foo knows who it is and it can define its name in its build scripts, is it?